# how to convert part of XML to string and store it in a variable using Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a below scenario:

1. During run time I want to take whole request and place in response
2. Request is in XML format
3. I want to take that request and store it in a variable either it is in string or XML also fine
   4.It should be done with Java script

I am able to take the request and convert it to JSON with JSON.Stringify function. In the same way is there any function to read directly as XML or converting XML to String and store it in a variable?

Comment: I treid String(XML object) and xml serializer but no luck

Comment: For converting to JSON I found simple function JSON.stringify but XML i didnt found any thing